# Magento2 set multiple table rate using shipping suite extension

Tags: magento2

1. I need user to see table rate quote for SpeeDee service if order is shipping to the region
2. For that i have multiple range of zip code (53001-53299,etc..)
3. For each range i have different weight(e.g. 0,1 etc)
4. For each weight i have different price (4.8, 5.2, etc)

e.g.

```
Range, Weight, Price
1. 53001-53299, 0, 4.8 
2. 53001-53299, 1, 5.2
3. 53300-53399, 0, 4.9
3. 53300-53399, 1, 5.3
```

I am using shipping suite module of mageworx

Comment: Did you manage to resolve that issue? I am developer of that extension so in case you are stuck I can help you :)